# UIScrollView background pattern image

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimage

I'm trying to implement a scrollable image resembling a shelf with UIButtons as books.

Using the first method, I'm setting the shelf as the UIImage background of the scroller. This looks perfectly fine, except the shelf image doesn't scroll.

Here's what that looks like

[image]

I tried a second method, which is just setting the background color of the scroller to a pattern image version of the shelf image.

Here's my code for the second version:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    [self.scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 700)];
    UIImage *shelfImage =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Shelf.jpeg"];
    self.scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:shelfImage];
}
```

And here's the (messed up) image :

[image]

**Main Question:** How can I make this pattern image look like the first image at the top?

Comment: Are you supplying a retina and non-retina image for your shelf image? What are their respective dimensions?

Comment: I'm not....the dimensions of the Shelf image are 197x255

Comment: I just tried resizing the shelf image, and it's a bit better. But is there an easier way instead of manually guessing the correct resize dimensions?

Comment: Well, since the background is so complex you pretty much need to resize it to the width to the iPhone (320px). From there, when you do `-colorWithPatternImage` the pattern should repeat appropriately. There isn't much "guessing" involved since every iOS device ever created that isn't a tablet has a width of 320px at 1x resolution.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the iPhone? 320 by 700?

Comment: For a 3.5-inch display like on the iPhone 4S and older, it's 320x480. For a 4-inch display like on the iPhone 5, it's 320x568.

(These heights include the status bar, which is 20pt in height on both)

Comment: Make use of UItableview instead of UIScrollView

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `UITableView` instead. In this you can set `cell.backgroundView` easily.

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake:(0.0,0.0,320.0, height)];
backgroundView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Shelf.jpeg"];
cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
```

And If you really want to use only `UIScrollView` then take only one cell background image and image width should be same of scrollView's width because `colorWithPatternImage:` method work like tiled property.

[image]

Take Only this image into your project and use it as `backgroundColor` of `UIScrollView`.

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0, 1000.0)];
[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellImage.png"]]];
```

It will look like this:

[image]

But I would like to suggest you again to use `UITableView` instead of `UIScrollView`.